# Problems with arrays within structures and files in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, structure

I'm trying to store information of the name of a lesson and the day(s) I have that lesson using structures in C. Storing the name hasn't been an issue. The problem occurs when I try and store multiple days (weekdays as integers, ie. Monday = 1) in an array.

This is what I have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct lessons{

   char name[20];
   int day[3];

};

changelessons(){

    int i, k;
    struct lessons give[1], receive[1];

    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen("lessons","wb");

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\n\t ~ Change lessons ~");
    printf("\n\nWhat's the lesson called?: ");
    gets(give[0].name);

    printf("\nHow many days do you have it?\n");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++); {  // Asks the weekday number for each day you have the lesson
        printf("What day is lesson %d?: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &give[0].day[i]);
    }

    fwrite(give, sizeof(give), 1, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);

    fptr = fopen("lessons", "rb");
    fread(receive, sizeof(receive), 1, fptr);

    printf("\n\t ~ Updated information: ~\n\nLesson name: %s\nDay: %d", receive[0].name, receive[0].day[1]);

    for(i = 1; i < k; i++); {  // Prints the extra weekdays if there are any
        printf(", day: %d", receive[0].day[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    fclose(fptr);
}

showlessons(){

    struct lessons give[1], receive[1];

    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen("lessons", "rb");
    fread(receive, sizeof(receive), 1, fptr);

    printf("\t ~ Current information: ~ \n\nLesson name: %s\nDay: %d\n\n", receive[0].name, receive[0].day[0]);

}

int main(){

  showlessons();
  changelessons();

  return 0;
}
```

Also, in the first for loop it only ever loops once regardless of what k equals.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < k; i++); {` Here you used a single-statement for for's body. So the following `{}` body will be executed once.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = 0; i < k; i++);
```

should be

```
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
```

The extra semi colon is a problem. Your loop code is not part of a loop. The semi colon terminates the loop.

Answer (score 1):

[nicomp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169091/nicomp) pointed out the most obvious error.

But I would also like to point out a few issues I have with your code:

1. `fflush(stdin);` This is wrong, undefined behaviour. `fflush` is used to
   flusg output streams, `stdin` is an input stream. See [Using
   `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/1480131).

   I know that in Windows `fflush(stdin)` clears the input buffer, but I strongly
   recommend not to use it, because you lose portability when relaying on features
   available only in one OS. If you don't care about portability, then use it. If
   you use that because `scanf` left stuff in the input buffer, use this instead:

   ```
   int c;
   while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
   ```

   This is portable.
2. Never ever use `gets` in 2018. `gets` is an unsafe, dangerous functions that
   has been deprecated in C99 and for good reasons: it doesn't take the size of the
   buffer into consideration and if the text entered is longer than the buffer can
   store, it will overflow the buffer. This is an accident waiting to happen. So,
   never ever use `gets` again. Use `fgets` instead and if you don't want to have
   a newline, you can remove it:

   ```
   fgets(give[0].name, sizeof give[0].name, stdin);
   give[0].name[sizeof(give[0].name) - 1] = 0; // remove possible newline
   ```
3. Why do you declare an array of `struct lessons` with dimension 1? What's the
   point? You don't need an array for this. You could write it like this:

   ```
   struct lessons give, receive;
   ...

   printf("\n\nWhat's the lesson called?: ");
   fgets(give.name, sizeof give.name, stdin);
   give.name[strcspn(give.name, "\n")] = 0;

   ...

   fwrite(&give, sizeof give, 1, fptr);
   fclose(fptr);

   ...

   fptr = fopen("lessons", "rb");
   fread(&receive, sizeof receive, 1, fptr);
   ```

   Also don't forget to check the return values of `fwrite` and `fread`.
4. Check the return value of `fopen`, if it returns `NULL`, you cannot use
   `fread` or `fwrite`. Print an error value and return/exit.
5. `stdout` is buffered and when you write to it with `printf`, it won't
   necessarily print the characters on screen right away. An exception is when
   `stdout` is connected to a terminal and a newline is written with `printf`. For
   user interaction this is great, because the user would see the output
   immediately. That's why most people print a newline along the text.

   If you don't do that but you still want that the user immediately sees the
   output, then this time you should use `fflush`:

   ```
    printf("What day is lesson %d?: ", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &give[0].day[i]);
   ```

   I don't know if there's a guarantee that `scanf` flushes `stdout` when it's
   connected to a terminal, regardless it is good practice to use `fflush(stdout)`
   when you don't print a newline at the end.